# What happens if a creature has no toughness defined?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Dominaria introduced [Merfolk Trickster](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMerfolk%20Trickster%5d), which causes a creature to lose all abilities, without setting a power and toughness.

What happens if a card such as [Tarmogoyf](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTarmogoyf%5d) loses all abilities?

Would Tarmagoyf become a 0/0 in this case, because a number not defined is treated as 0? Or would it possibly be a 0/1, because the printed toughness on the card is "*+1", and only the "`*`" part is undefined? What about a card like [Boneyard Wurm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBoneyard%20Wurm%5d), would it just become 0/0 (and thus die)?

There seems to be a possible contradiction between the comprehensive rules and the Gatherer rulings. The Gatherer rulings say:

> If the target creature has power and toughness written as */* with an ability that defines its power and toughness, it’s 0/0 when it loses all abilities. **If its power and toughness are written as */*+1, it’s 0/1**, and so on.

Rule 208.5 deals with this situation:

> 208.5. If a creature somehow has no value for its power, its power is 0. The same is true for toughness.

It seems to me that a Tarmagoyf that loses all abilities has no toughness defined. It's toughness is written as "*/1+*", which according to 208.2, its toughness should be defined by its abilities.

So, while it is clear that a */* creature will be a 0/0 if it loses all abilities; what happens to a */*+1? Is it 0/0 or 0/1?

Also, I find it interesting, though not likely relevant, that Tarmogoyf is written "*/1+*" (with the 1 first), while the Gatherer ruling references cards that are "*/*+1" (with the * first).

Comment: I have updated this question in response to Merfolk Trickster, and unaccepted the accepted answer; which may or may not still be correct.

Answer (score 22):

With the introduction of Vehicles in the set Kaladesh, this situation is now possible and explicitly covered by the rules.

> **208.5** If a creature somehow has no value for its power, its power is 0. The same is true for toughness.

Comment: Neat! Can you provide an example of how a vehicle might have no power or toughness defined?

Comment: There's a question about it here: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/33497/how-on-earth-do-i-crew-a-non-vehicle; short version is you give a vehicle's Crew ability to something that's not a vehicle or creature.

Answer (score 17):

This question is hypothetical and not covered by the rules. All [current cards which cause a creature to lose all abilities](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=%20%5B%22loses%20all%20abilities%22%5D) also set the power/toughness of the creature, or cause it to no longer be a creature making the power/toughness irrelevant.

It's a safe bet that  *loses all abilities* cards are designed that way to avoid this conundrum.

Comment: It's not clear from that rules quote that this is correct. "If the ability needs to use a number that can’t be determined, use 0..." But this isn't a case of the ability not being able to determine the number. In this case, the ability doesn't exist.

Comment: @ghoppe I think we all agree that you can't determine the value of the asterisk. But with the ability removed, 208.2a can't apply - there's no ability for it to apply to - so it seems that there's nothing here to determine what the asterisk means. So is there another rule that explains how to determine the value of a placeholder like the asterisk when there's no ability?

Comment: @Jefromi Yes it took me a minute to consider the argument, and I agree. I've changed my answer.

Comment: @Jefromi It is interesting that 208.2a and 208.2b both say that the creature "may" have an ability that sets the stats, but no mention of what to do when they don't have that ability. I think their intent was to say that such a creature will either have one or the other at all times.

Comment: I'm not super good at old cards, and I don't know how to search on Gatherer for an asterisk in power/toughness - were there any of those guys early on? I'm sure the current rules were written with the knowledge that this can't happen, but I'm not as sure about the early lose-abilities card designs. (Humility isn't exactly a poster child for avoiding nasty rules interactions...)

Comment: @Jefromi Yes, old-timers will remember [Nightmare](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370689) from Alpha. These cards have always been in the game. It's likely because of Nightmare that *loses all abilities* cards are designed the way they are.

Comment: @ghoppe Ah, that's the name, thanks! I thought there was something old and black and scary, and somehow couldn't come up with it, despite the recent reprints.

Comment: [Sudden Spoiling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376529) is not caught by that search due to a 1-letter difference.  And [Lignify](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=201837) says "with no abilities".  There may be others that also use slightly different wording

Comment: This is objectively a worse answer than the one by Michael Snook.

Comment: @SoldierofVol Which isn't surprising considering Michael Snook answered the question two years after I did, after the rules changed and explicitly covered the situation. ;-)

Comment: You can always update this answer to include more accurate information.

Comment: This is no longer true with [Ray of frost](https://scryfall.com/card/afr/68/ray-of-frost) also, the alchemy card [Patriar's humiliation](https://scryfall.com/card/hbg/999-PTH/patriars-humiliation) that doesn't have the color restriction

Answer (score 9):

Tarmogoyf will be a 0/1 in this case.

As long as Tarmogoyf is missing its characteristic defining ability, the only information available for determining its power and toughness are the ***/*+1** printed on the card. So, it's not exactly accurate to say that it has no value for it's power, but rather, it has a value determined by an undefined symbol, and a calculation involving that symbol. In that case, [rule 107.2](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Numbers_and_symbols) applies:

> If anything needs to use a number that can’t be determined, either as a result or in a calculation, it uses 0 instead.

Since the start symbol has a value that can't be determined, the Tarmogoyf's power and toughness are evaluated as **0/1+0**, or **0/1**.

Similarly, Boneyard Wurm's power and toughness is printed as ***/***, which would evaluate to **0/0** while it has no abilities.

Comment: So, you're saying a \*/\* creature like [Nightmare](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=429906) would have 0 toughness and die?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying. I added a bit covering that in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

There have been no printed cards that remove static abilities without also setting the power and toughness (Snakeform, Ovinize) or changing the card to no longer be a creature ([Soul Sculptor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=9846)) as stated in ghoppe's answer.

Tarmogoyf's ability which sets its power and toughness is in a special class of static abilities called `characteristic-defining abilities [CR 604.3]` which function in all zones and even outside of the game. Any hypothetical card which exclusively removed static abilities would need a special ruling on its interaction with these type of abilities.

Asterisks `*` representing power and/or toughness are treated as 0 (even within calculations) in the case of static abilities that create replacement effects [208.2b] and also characteristic defining abilities when the value of the asterisk cannot be determined.

In addition to these definitions, Gatherer also treats asterisks as zeros with constants added continuing to be added. To find Tarmogoyf in Gatherer by Power and Toughness alone, one must set the search parameters to Power=0 and Toughness=1.

It is reasonable to assume that any future ruling would be consistent with this and set completely undefined asterisks to zero, although this is just speculation on my part.

If we assume that the above proves true then we can make the following conclusions regarding the specific creatures mentioned in the question.
 - If Tarmogoyf somehow lost his ability which defines the value of `*`,
   then each `*` would be taken as equal to 0 so that it would become
   0 / 1+0 => 0/1. 
 - Boneyard Wurm would become a 0/0 and thus under `[CR 704.5f]`, be put
   into its owners graveyard. (Of course, once in the graveyard its power and toughness would be reset based on its characteristic-defining ability)

The rulings for [Nightmare](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370689) help clarify some of the interactions with asterisks in power/toughness.

> If you control 0 swamps, then the Nightmare has 0 toughness and will be put into its owner's graveyard as a state-based action right before the next player gains priority.
>
> Nightmare's power and toughness changes as the number of Swamps you control changes.
>
> The ability that defines Nightmare’s power and toughness works everywhere, not just on the battlefield.

### EDIT

[CR 208.2a] in reference to Asterisks in Power and Toughness

> This ability functions everywhere, even outside the game. If the ability needs to use a number that can’t be determined, including inside a calculation, use 0 instead of that number.
>
> Example: Lost Order of Jarkeld has power and toughness each equal to 1+*. It has the abilities “As Lost Order of Jarkeld enters the battlefield, choose an opponent” and “Lost Order of Jarkeld’s power and toughness are each equal to 1 plus the number of creatures the chosen player controls.” While Lost Order of Jarkeld isn’t on the battlefield, there won’t be a chosen player. Its power and toughness will each be equal to 1 plus 0, so it’s 1/1.

Comment: It's not clear if the undefined quantity that would become zero would be * or *+1, since the rules don't explain anywhere what we must do if a sum appears where the thoughness should be. That's why it is unclear if Tarmogoyf would be a 0/0 or a 0/1. That's why this situation is currently not covered by the rules.

Comment: "Asterisks * representing power and/or toughness are treated as 0 (even within calculations) when the value of the asterisk cannot be determined." Can you find a rule for this? I don't think there is one.

Comment: I guess I should have quoted the one rule that was under most contention. The comprehensive rules are very clear that what I said is correct. I will post the example within the CR that further explains the asterisk rule.

Comment: @JRaccoon The rule you've quoted was discussed on the other question too. The issue is that the rule is explaining how the *ability containing the asterisk works*. But we're talking about a situation where the ability has been removed. 208.2a is talking about how a certain kind of ability functions... but now there is no such ability, so 208.2a doesn't apply any more than it applies to your Grizzly Bears that never had an ability like that in the first place.

Comment: @JRaccoon Now, if there actually were cards that removed abilities without setting power/toughness, I'm sure that they would fix the rules such that the asterisk was 0 as you've said, and it wouldn't be a hard fix to make. But the rules as written don't actually say "here's how you figure out what value an asterisk has". They talk about how the *ability* works.

Comment: @Jefromi Of course, as there are no rules that explicitly remove these static abilities, we can't say for sure what the official ruling would be. Based on the wording of all related rules, if a card that removed static abilities was printed with no changes to the rules, a judge would have no choice but to rule that the asterisk represented a 0 while any constants added to it remained.

Comment: Exactly. The comp rules as written are *not* clear that  this is correct. I'm sure you're right that a judge would rule in this way in a hypothetical scenario, or if they needed to fix this gap in the rules they'd fix it this way, but it's really misleading to claim that they actually say so already.

Comment: I said "Any hypothetical card which exclusively removed static abilities would need a special ruling on its interaction with these type of abilities." I don't see how that is promoting anything not explicitly in the rules. I edited my post to include the rule asked by Gendolkari in the comments, which is correct and directly quoted. The examples of Tarmogoyf and Boneyard Wurm were just to illustrate how when the value asterisks change, the card is subject to being sent to the graveyard when its toughness reaches zero and *when* the asterisk is zero, other constants *are* added to it.

Comment: Yes, you said new rulings would be needed, but then you go on to say "If Tarmogoyf somehow lost his ability which defines the value of *, then each * would be taken as equal to 0 so that it would become 0 / 1+0 => 0/1." You don't say "this is hypothetical, how I think it should/could work", you present it as fact. It sounds like you actually agree with everything that was said in the top answer (and in the comments to it) and you're trying to present some more detail, but you're doing so in a misleading way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14371/discussion-between-jraccoon-and-jefromi)

Comment: This is no longer true with [Ray of frost](https://scryfall.com/card/afr/68/ray-of-frost) also,the alchemy card [Patriar's humiliation](https://scryfall.com/card/hbg/999-PTH/patriars-humiliation) that doesn't have the color restriction