# How on earth do I crew a non-vehicle?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The [Kaladesh update bulletin](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/kaladesh-update-bulletin-2016-09-30) includes the following line:

> #### 208.5
>
> Also on the subject of power and toughness, we have a new rule that if a creature has no power or toughness, that value is 0. This can happen if you manage to get a crew ability to animate a non-Vehicle artifact.

The newly defined rule itself says:

> **208.5** If a creature somehow has no value for its power, its power is 0. The same is true for toughness.

The update bulletin doesn't mention what cards could possibly enable this to happen though, and I can't for the life of me figure out how this gets set up. Is it some combo involving [Necrotic Ooze](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNecrotic%20Ooze%5d) or something?

**How can I crew a non-vehicle to arrive at this situation?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest method of accomplishing this probably involves using a [Mizzium Transreliquat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMizzium%20Transreliquat%5d). Say you control a Mizzium Transreliquat, a [Sol Ring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSol%20Ring%5d), a [Smuggler's Copter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSmuggler%27s%5d%2b%5bCopter%5d), and a [Grizzly Bears](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrizzly%20Bears%5d). Then you can get the situation the bulletin is referring to by doing the following:

1. Activate and resolve the Mizzium Transreliquat's second ability targeting the Copter.
2. Activate the copy's Crew ability.
3. While that is on the stack, activate and resolve the Mizzium Transreliquat ability again targeting Sol Ring.
4. Let the Crew ability resolve, animating a copy of a Sol Ring.